# Angular Observe DOM loop without Subscription?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using `Angular 5 (or 2+)`.

**What I Have**

- I have a CSS fixed element (Intercom App Chat Bubble in an iframe, Absolute/Fixed position).
- Since the elements cannot change in CSS due to `fixed/absolute` position I need to use JS.
- The chat bubble sometimes is overlaps the text editor.

**What I Want to Do:** Move the Chat bubble when overlapped. (I can handle that part)`.

**Question with Angular**

- Does Angular have a loop that always runs for the DOM?
- Must I use RxJS subscription for ~3+ events *(Window sizing, scrolling, resizing text editor)*?

> Or would use of `setInterval` every `5 sec` or so be reasonable?

I'd really appreciate any suggestion or point me to the docs where the best option to do this is at :)

Comment: Sounds like this question is related to `Angular` instead. Switching. That said, please provide more informations, this is likely not enough to provide a valuable response.

Comment: Theres a SO angular?

Comment: Angularjs referes to angularjs, Angular referes to Angular2 (and RC.X and next versions) (check tag descriptions) (We're talking about tags)

Comment: okay, does that seem okay?

Comment: `Does Angular have a loop that always runs for the DOM?` Angular 2 uses a Change Detection System, you may want to check it ;).